# TP-Link TL-WN321G Driver Lubuntu 14.04 Install

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, adapter

i downloaded the drivers from the main site but i did not understand correctly how to install on Lubuntu 14.04.
What's the correct way?

http://www.tp-link.it/resources/software/200912314051713.zip here are the drivers

Thanks!

Comment: The driver it compiles, _rt73usb_, is built in to Ubuntu 14.04 by default. Is it not loading? Is it not working as expected? Please tell us more.

Comment: Output for sudo iwlist wlan0 scan is "Interface does not support scanning"

Comment: What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your wireless has the driver it needs, *rt73usb*. A wireless interface wlan0 is present. However, you are unable to select an available network because of a bug in lubuntu.

To fix the Network Manager not showing up on the panel issue, from the Lubuntu menu select Preferences > Default applications for LXSession, then click on the Autostart tab and under "Manual autostarted applications" type "nm-applet", then click the "+ Add" button on the left.

Now log out, log back in and you should see the Network Manager icon on the panel: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/fix-lubuntu-1404-network-manager.html

Once the Network Manager icon appears, select 'Enable Networking' and 'Enable Wireless.'

Comment: That's great. It worked instantly. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Ubuntu hasn't installed the driver automatically? Enter `ipconfig -a` in a terminal and check if there's a `wlan0`. If there is, it's probably already installed.

There may also be a driver available in `Additional Drivers` (search for it in your Dash). This is the easiest way to get it working.

I also found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSrTnWDTdwI) but it's for Ubuntu 10.04 so you may have to do things a bit different (for example I wouldn't install that `linux-firmware` package as it's probably outdated).

If you really want to install this yourself you can follow these steps:

1. First install the necessary stuff:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential unzip
   ```
2. Extract the `.zip` file:

   ```
   unzip 200912314051713-1.zip
   ```
3. Enter the `Module` directory:

   ```
   cd "Driver for TL-WN321G in Linux/Module"
   ```
4. Configure the driver:

   ```
   ./Configure
   ```
5. Compile the driver:

   ```
   make
   ```
6. Check if it compiled correctly:

   ```
   make test
   ```
7. Install the driver:

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```

Comment: Installed via Additional Drivers but i cannot see anything in the GUI(even after reboot) to connect to Wifi. What's the next step?

Comment: Do you see `wlan0` if you execute `ifconfig -a`? And what's the name of the driver you've installed?

Comment: `wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:27:ca:22:34  
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
`

It's just this.

Comment: And what if you click on the WiFi icon in the top right of your screen?

Comment: It's Lubuntu, icons are in the bottom right.However, i do not have any wifi icon(as i said in the first comment)

Comment: Oh I didn't see that. What's the output of `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`? You can put output of commands in your *question* instead of the comments.

Comment: I wrote the output of the command in the question as you said. Could you please check?